Is the final chunk always empty in Nginx's chunked transfer encoding? (ngx_http_top_body_filter)
I’m currently working with code that Nginx invokes, specifically dealing with the HTTP response body, and I have a question regarding the implementation of chunked transfer encoding in Nginx, particularly in relation to the ngx_http_top_body_filter.
From my understanding, chunked transfer encoding allows a server to send a response in a series of chunks, with a final chunk that has a length of 0 to indicate the end of the response. Is this behavior consistent in Nginx, or is there a need to add another chunk when writing an attachment to Nginx?

I looked at Wikipedia, which states that the final chunk in chunked transfer encoding is always of size 0, indicating the end of the response. However, I’m aware that this does not necessarily mean that the ngx_http_top_body_filter in Nginx will always trigger a last chunk of size 0. For example, in Envoy’s implementation of chunked transfer encoding, the last chunk of size 0 is not triggered.
I also reviewed the Nginx development guide (https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html), but it does not explicitly mention whether ngx_http_top_body_filter will always trigger a final chunk of size 0.
Given this, I’m uncertain if this behavior is obvious or if it needs to be explicitly handled when implementing an Nginx attachment. Should I expect that I need to account for this in my implementation, or is it implicit in the design of Nginx's handling of chunked transfer encoding?

If there's no chunk with size 0, how would the client know when the response is done?

I'm not really familiar with writing nginx filters, but I don't see anything in the documentation you linked to that says that you have to deal with chunks in your code. I think it should be handled automatically by nginx.

It looks like this will be done automatically if you haven't specified a content_length_n header.

Thanks! Where have you seen that content_length_n is necessary?

Regarding the client knowing this is the last chunk - using a boolean seems like a reasonable solution as well.

See the Response Header section of the documentation you linked to. If the response status indicates that a response body follows the header, content_length_n can be set as well.

What boolean are you referring to? You can't change the way the filter is called.
